# Как убрать зазоры в header CSS?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть тег header в CSS, нужно убрать зазоры пробывал с помощью margin ничего не вышло

Comment: Вообще, чтобы не заморачиваться с таким вот обнулением, рекомендую bootstrap reboot, его во многие стартеры добавляют https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/reboot/

Answer (score 0):

Нужно обнулить margin у body

```
body {margin: 0}
```